# How can I open/close Admob with Firebase Remote Config?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob, firebase-remote-config

I'm new to Flutter and Remote Config. In my project, I'm trying to close my ad banners from remote config like true/false statement but I think I'm missing something out. I would really appreciate if you give me any advice.

I imported remote plugin for flutter and made the android integration. After that I initialize it

```
Future<RemoteConfig> setupRemoteConfig() async {
  final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;
  // Enable developer mode to relax fetch throttling
  remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(debugMode: true));
  await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
  remoteConfig.setDefaults(<String, dynamic>{
    'admob_status': 'true',
  });
  return remoteConfig;
}
```

and after that, I added it below statement to my build widget.

```
var value = remoteConfig.getString("admob_status");

    if(value == "true"){
      FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId)
          .then((response) {
        myBanner
          ..load()
          ..show(
            //anchorOffset: 60.0,
              anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
      });
    } else if(value == "false") {
      return null;
    }
```

and output is "the method 'getString' was called on null."

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, it seems working. Maybe it can help you in the future

```
checkAdmobStatus() async {
    final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;

    final defaults = <String, dynamic>{'status': 'true'};
    await remoteConfig.setDefaults(defaults);

    await remoteConfig.fetch();
    await remoteConfig.activateFetched();

    if ('true' == remoteConfig.getString('status')) {
      FirebaseAdMob.instance
          .initialize(appId: FirebaseAdMob.testAppId)
          .then((response) {
        myBanner
          ..load()
          ..show(anchorType: AnchorType.bottom);
      });
    }
  }
```